# MVC 3 N-Tier app - Execution Engine Exception trying to update record using context.Entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dbcontext

I am developing an n-tier application in MVC 3.  I am working with an existing database so have used the database first approach and created POCO’s in my domain layer using the DbContext generator. 
I am having no problem performing an insert on the database using:

```
context.Programmes.Add(programme); //where programme is a programme object
```

However I had real problems finding programmes by Id using:

```
Context.Programmes.Find(id); //where I was passing the primary key value in as Id.
```

I can’t remember what error that was throwing but I did some research and heard it was something to do with the naming convention with keys using this approach?? Anyway I got round it by using:

```
return context.Programmes.Single(u => u.ProgrammeId == ProgrammeId);
```

Now I am struggling with updating a record using:

```
context.Entry(Find(programme.ProgrammeId)).CurrentValues.SetValues(programme);
```

This doesn’t work and throws an execution engine exception

but if I take the old record and manually map the updated values using:

```
var oldVals = context.Programmes.Single(u => u.ProgrammeId == programme.ProgrammeId);
```

and then:

```
oldVals.ProgrammeState = programme.ProgrammeState;
oldVals.ProgrammeVersion = programme.ProgrammeVersion;
oldVals.Title = programme.Title;
oldVals.ProgrammeCode = programme.ProgrammeCode;
oldVals.Division = programme.Division; oldVals.Faculty
...etc (there are quite a few more fields)
```

This seems to work fine.
I think I have isolated the root of the problem and it seems to relate to using context.Entry and the error I’m getting is: 
Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
Any help with this will be really appreciated, whilst I could manually map the updates I’m pretty sure it isn’t best practice!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution so thought I'd post it just in case this proves useful to anybody else:

In my domain layer I had referenced Entity Framework 4.1 - just had to delete it and add reference 4.2 to use Find and Entry etc.

Also for information the references in the service layer and the MVC layer all need to be pointing to the same entity dll - have noticed that sometimes these can vary - even if it is the same version sometimes it is a different file - I had to make sure all mine were:

C:\Visual Studio Projects..etc...\packages\EntityFramework.4.2.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll

Once I had this right I was able to use:

```
return context.Programmes.Find(ProgrammeId);
```

and:

a more elegant update:

```
context.Entry(programme).State = EntityState.Modified;
```